# Change href on Title in list view to go to specific custom Display Form

Tags: display-form, recurring-events

I am working with a Calendar with **Recurring Events**. I want to have two different display forms for different audiences.

I can not create new/modify/customize the Display forms since that breaks the display of the event times (for recurring events). So, I just copy and paste **DispForm.aspx**, rename it to **DispForm_Copy.aspx** and leave it as is using SPD. I then make client-side modifications to each of these pages using Script Editor and Content Editors.

I now have Page A (for Audience A) that has a list view with the Title linking to Dispform.aspx for the item, and Page B (for Audience B) that has a list view with the Title linking to DispForm_Copy.aspx. These views were created with the instances expanded, so each instance of the recurring event shows as a single row.

Page A is no problem - I just use a Title (linked to item) column which uses the default Dispform.aspx.

**Question:** How do I modify Page B so that the href on the Title link to goes to DispForm_Copy.aspx, while maintaining the same item ID and parameters - so that it still links to the correct instance of the recurring event?

I have also tried creating a separate Hyperlink column and building this using Workflow, but then I can't figure out how to build the link so that it goes to the single instance of the event. If someone has that answer then please share that as well!

I'm hoping to do this with OOTB sharepoint, client-side rendering and or jquery or SPD Workflows.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you,
Maureen